# Broke My Site With WP Rocket - Failed to set referrer policy broke my site

Tags: wordpress, referrer-policy

I installed WP Rocket and it broke my site (www.calvinwright.org). I've removed it, cleared my cache and even deactivated every plugin on my site to see. It's still not returning and I don't know what to do. Any advice/suggestions are beyond appreciated.

Again, calvinwright.org for reference.

If it has something to do with my .htcaccess file, here's what it looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

THANK YOU.

Comment: Is Visual Code page builder plugin active?

Comment: @Manjunath No, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can install **W3 Total Cache** and follow this instructions: [WordPress Failed to Set Referrer Policy Response Headers – W3 Total Cache](https://623lafayette.com/2018/05/02/wordpress-failed-to-set-referrer-policy/)